"с краешку" или "с краешка"?
Как правильно сказать - "присел с краешку" или "присел с краешка"?
Грамота.ру настаивает, что правильно "с краешка". Грамматически это действительно выглядит правильнее, но "с краешку" часто встречается в литературе, и вообще выглядит как часть устоявшегося оборота.

С чего? - с краешка, где? - с краешку. Пересел с краешка и присел с краешку. "Присела с краешку сама. — Тебе налить, тетка Анисья?" Шукшин.

Вот только поиск в нацкорпусе показывает, что "с краешка" тоже используется, и в том же самом контексте.

приведите пример, что ли

Так посмотрите нацкорпус, адрес известен https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnQiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGwoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4AKABATICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHRgSDQutGA0LDQtdGI0LrQsA==

Правильно (по норме):
Русский орфографический словарь
край, -я и -ю, предл. в крае и в краю, на краю, мн. края, краёв
краешек, -шка

Итак, мы видим только один нормативный вариант окончания для сущ. краешек, и два варианта для сущ. край. В реальных художественных текстах варианты исключить нельзя. Но как правильно и какова причина вариантов?

Существование двух вариантов окончаний для сущ. м.р. — тема известная, в частности материал есть у Розенталя:

§152. Окончания родительного падежа единственного числа существительных мужского рода -а(-я) – -у(-ю)
Розенталь определяет тематику таких существительных (вещественные, собирательные, отвлеченные, фразеологизмы). Также он указывает на возможные колебания, например в составе фрзеологизмов:
  Примечание. Некоторые существительные, входящие в состав 
  фразеологизмов, допускают варианты родительного падежа: с 
  испугу/испуга (крикнуть), до зарезу/зареза (нужно), без 
  спросу/спроса (войти), без разбору/разбора (брать), без 
  счету/счета (сорить деньгами), то же самое касается 
  некоторых существительных, употребляющихся в отрицательных 
  конструкциях износу/износа нет, отбою/отбоя нет, отказу/ 
  отказа не было, покою/покоя нет.

Поэтому выбор варианта может зависеть от стиля.

Из других источников:

Варианты окончаний –у/-ю и –а/-я родительного падежа единственного числа мужского рода
 Стакан чаю – стакан крепкого чая
 Ложка меду – чайная ложка меда
 Метр ситцу – метр дешевого ситца
 Много народу – история народа
 Натерпеться страху – не знать страха
 Сколько визгу – не слышно визга
 Спору нет – отказаться от спора


Общая тенденция

Наблюдается тенденция к унификации в пользу окончания -а/-я.
В XIX веке нормативными для лит. языка считались формы на ~а/~я, преобладавшие формы на -у/-ю считались разговорными. И в совр.лит-ре более широкое использование форм на -а/-я: стакан чая, много народа. В устной речи молодые предпочитают формы на -а/-я, а старшие на -у /-ю: стакан чаю, куча снегу, много воздуху.
Идет постепенное вытеснение формы на –у/-ю формой на –а/-я. Степень интенсивности этого процесса зависит от: + стиля речи, + частоты употребления лексического сочетания + характера конструкции (глагольная, именная), + типа синтаксич конструкции, степени фразеологизации, экспрессивности и т.д.

ПРИЧИНОЙ существования вариантов является, то что раньше склонение зависело от основы (было 6 вариантов склонения), а затем некоторые склонения исчезли, другие расширились (в частности 2-е склонение для сущ. м. рода). В конечном итоге склонение стало в большей степени соотноситься с родом существительных.



Как правильно сказать - "присел с краешку" или "присел с краешка"?
Грамота.ру настаивает, что правильно "с краешка".

Грамота.ру неправа. Верны оба варианта — и с краешка, и с краешку.
Я бы выбрал второй, к тому же именно он и присутствует в «Иллюстрированном толковом словаре современного русского языка» В. В. Лопатина:



